# Передача параметров IN OUT процедуры oracle в javа приложение

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, plsql

Необходимо передать в приложение парамаетры, возвращаемые хранимой процедурой Oracle. 
Сама процедура

```
 PROCEDURE REMOVAL_ATR_PR340_FR73_S1_T1(p_POE_STEAM_TURBINES_VID NUMBER, p_PERIOD_ID NUMBER,
p_STOP_ID in out number, p_REMOVAL_LAST_YEAR in out NUMBER)
IS
BEGIN       
    SELECT pr.STOP_ID, pr.REMOVAL_LAST_YEAR
    INTO p_STOP_ID, p_REMOVAL_LAST_YEAR
    FROM FORMS fr LEFT JOIN PR340_FR73_S1_T1 pr
    ON pr.FORMS_ID = fr.ID
    WHERE PERIOD_ID = p_PERIOD_ID - 1
    AND pr.POE_STEAM_TURBINES_VID = p_POE_STEAM_TURBINES_VID;
END REMOVAL_ATR_PR340_FR73_S1_T1;
```

Код её вызывающий

```
String sql = "{call REA.FILL_EVENT.REMOVAL_ATR_PR340_FR73_S1_T1("  + doc.poeSteamTurbine.vid + "," + doc.form.periodId +"," + 0 +  "," + 0 +") } ";
    CallableSql cs = Ebean.createCallableSql(sql);
    cs.registerOut(3, Types.INTEGER);
    cs.registerOut(4, Types.INTEGER);
    Ebean.execute(cs);
    Integer retValue = (Integer) cs.getObject(3);
```

В результате возникает ошибка

```
play.api.Application$$anon$1: Execution exception[[PersistenceException: java.sql.SQLException: Недопустимый индекс столбца]]
```

Процедура без проблем работает в связке с триггером, так как он передает именно переменные в которые процедура кладет значения. Как это должно выглядеть в java?

Comment: а как вы используете полученный `sql`. куда его передает?

Comment: Извиняюсь за неполный код, дополнил

Comment: вы используете Ebean ORM?

Comment: да, хочу  сделать как здесь https://ebean-orm.github.io/apidocs/com/avaje/ebean/CallableSql.html

Comment: Сделал как по мануалу, теперь другая ошибка

Answer (score 1):

Надо было внимательнее читать документацию Ebean ORM и следовать приведенному там примеру. Данный код работает :

```
 String sql = "{call REA.FILL_EVENT.REMOVAL_ATR_PR340_FR73_S1_T1(?,?,?,?) } ";
        CallableSql cs = Ebean.createCallableSql(sql);
        cs.setParameter(1,doc.poeSteamTurbine.vid);
        cs.setParameter(2,doc.form.periodId);
        cs.registerOut(3, Types.INTEGER);
        cs.registerOut(4, Types.INTEGER);
        Ebean.execute(cs);
        doc.prevStopId = (Integer) cs.getObject(3);
        doc.prevRemovalLastYear = (Integer) cs.getObject(4);
        return doc;
```